# How to fix pnmscale/pnmtojpeg: command not found

Tags: linux, image-processing, image-manipulation, centos

```
-bash: pnmscale: command not found
-bash: pnmtojpeg: command not found
```

I thought these are part of netpbm?  Anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried `pamscale`? That replaced `pnmscale`. Is the netpbm package installed? What OS are you using? And if Linux, which distro?

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnmscale.html) helps. (web search)

Comment: I tried pamscale before but it gave me the same thing.  I have pnmscale installed.  CENTOS 5.6 x86_64

Comment: opps..  Meant I have netpbm installed

Answer (score 11):

I was unaware that I had to also install netpbm-progs and netpbm-devel besides the basic netpbm.  That solved the problem.

Comment: I was looking for the program pngtopnm and installing netpbm-progs was the key.